# Mapbox gl change poi_label name style using geocoder search result

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox gl for showing POI in using the geocoder. for some reason, the location of most of the poi is not accurate, because this marker is not getting placed on the POI. Is it possible to change the poi label style based upon the search result? I know using setLayoutProperty we can change all the poi label names but I want to change the specific poi name which comes out of the geocoder search result. Any help is much appreciated.

Adding more information, I'm creating a marker using the geocoder results, however, there were a good amount of restaurants whose marker is positioned away from the actual location. Maybe because of the incorrect coordinates. So the idea is to change the style of the restaurant name in the map instead of creating a maker, this will remove the marker floating around the wrong location.
My question is it possible to do such kind of styling or is there a way we can get more accurate coordinates. I could able to see using SetLayoutProperty for "POI_LABLE" we can change the styles of the name attribute. Is it possible to apply a filter here and change the style of the matched name?. Thanks for looking into this question.

Comment: Can you give an example of a bad result, and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Styles which use Mapbox Streets data show POIs from OpenStreetMap data unless you are in Japan, this is documented at https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/#data-sources--updates.

According to https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/geocoding/#source-data,

> The Mapbox Geocoding API contains data sources from governments, open data projects, and private companies. In some cases, results from the Geocoding API may differ from Mapbox Streets or OpenStreetMap data.

So the POI results from the Mapbox Geocoder aren't guaranteed to be the same as those POIs shown on the map as they come from different data sources, hence won't always be in the same location and aren't linked with any form of ID.